# Implement one-to-many relationship in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

This is my project model :

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Proposal> Proposals{ get; set; }

}
```

This is my Proposal model :

```
public class Proposal
{
    public int ProposalID { get; set; }
    public string BidTitle { get; set; }
    public string BidDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there is one-to-many relationship between Project and Proposal. In

> mydomain/Project/Details/ProjectID

view, I want to put a button, when this button is clicked, user can create a new Proposal for that project. My question is how I can pass that project's information to bid?  If you can give me some tips about it, I'd be really glad. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how to get project entity ? And when a button you redirect to another page

Comment: Yes, when user clicks button, user will go to mydomain/Proposal/Create, I want to get projectID of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say when user click button user goto another page. You can sen projectID as get to that page. Thats how you can get that projectID.

Comment: Could you explain with a simple example?

Comment: you can send in this way mydomain/Proposal/Create?projectId={projectId}

Comment: And then how should I retrieve projectId in Create page? Thank you

Comment: public ActionResult Create(int projectId=0){}
new actiontion automatically get projectId 
and if pass nothing then projectId will get 0

Answer (score 1):

Create a model known as a viewmodel, which includes both the models you want to use under the same view. Your would look something like this:

```
public class ProposalAndProjectModel
    {              
        public Proposal Proposal { get; set; }
        public Project Project{ get; set; }    
    }
```

Save it as something like ProposalAndProjectModel.cs and then in your view, reference this model.

Now in your view you will be able to do the following:

```
Model.Proposal.propertyName
```

or

```
Model.Project.propertyName
```

This should help you as for getting the correct parameters for creating new objects.